# Nodejs silent push notification is not working in iOS 13

Tags: node.js, ios13

we are able to generate silent push notifications from firebase console to ios devices ( via APNS ) when the app is in the background - we have tested these and these are consistently received over long periods of the app in background ( ios 13 as well). however when we try and send the same silent notifications via our backend server ( which is node.js) then they aren't received? any solutions/ suggestions

```
let data = {
        key1:`Key1 Value`,
        key2:`Key2 Value`,
        notificationTime: new Date().toISOString()
    }
    const response = await admin.messaging().send({
        token,
        data,   
        apns: {
          headers:{
            'apns-push-type':'background',
            'apns-priority':'5',
            'apns-topic': 'com.packageName'
        },
        payload: {
          aps: {
            'content-available': 1,
            'alert':{
                'body':""
            }
          },
        },
      }      
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and all I did is the following:

1. Steps

   - Logout from your application
   - Remove the application
   - Restart your phone (Turn it off and turn it on after ~30 seconds)
   - Install the app once again
   - Login
   - Send the app to background / Kill it from the processes
   - Send the silent push notification

It looks like restarting the phone did the trick in my case.